# antd badge number is resized incorrectly

Tags: reactjs, frontend, antd, badge, ant-design-pro

I'm trying to use antd's badge, but the number+badge always looks out of sync with the icon no matter which icon I use.

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the problem:

I have antd's badge imported correctly, NotificationOutlined imported properly, and antd is 4.0+. I have attempted using CSS and playing with fontSize but it does not doing anything.

Code:

```
<Badge count={5}>
      <NotificationOutlined  />
 </Badge>
```

I'd appreciate any guesses/ insight to how I can solve this!
Source: https://ant.design/components/badge/

Comment: Are you sure you haven't overwritten any antd default styles by mistake?

Comment: I think you're right, the default css was moved. do you know where I can happen to find the css for the badge? I'm a bit new but I looked in the antd directory and I see less but no css for the badge